# Jupyter notebook cant connect to arcgis Pro

Tags: python, jupyter, arcgis

I have connected to ArcGIS Pro and logged in and have it started in the background...
When i open jupyter and try to connect to Pro i get the error below
    ValueError: Could not use Pro authentication.

I tried starting jupyter from the 'All Programs' > ArcGIS > Jupyter notebook location but starting it from here just has "Kernal is starting". I originally installed jupyter seperately so i always run it from a shortcut, and not from all programs. heres my code

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from IPython.display import display
```

## for some reason it asks for arcpy when it isnt supposed to need to

## so i import that aswell

```
mygis = GIS("pro")     # Use ArcGIS Pro to connect
myaccount = mygis.users.me
myaccount
```

ValueError: Could not use Pro authentication.

I expect jupyter to connect to ArcGIS PRO

Comment: [The first parameter of the GIS object is the portal url to login to](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html). I garuntee you that your portal URL is not `pro`, thats not even a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out, I was right

What i had to do was open Jupyter from ARCGIS in the start menu
But before doing that you must open its file location and in that location type into the python command prompt

"python -m ipykernel install --user"

this will activate your kernal (mine is python 3)

Then with jupyter and arcgis Pro opened, do

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from IPython.display import display
mygis = GIS("pro")     # Use ArcGIS Pro to connect
myaccount = mygis.users.me
myaccount
```